# How to fill this hole between balcony deck and brick wall?

Tags: wood, brick, decking, hole-repair, balcony

What materials do I need to fill this hole on my 2nd floor balcony?  It's deeper than it looks. There's nothing for bondo or caulk to adhere to do not sure how to create a backing.

[image: closeup]

[image: Photo of the hole]

[image: another angle]

[image: deck level top view]

[image: deck level bottom view]

[image: ground level view]

[image: ground level closeup]

[image: ground level zoom]

Comment: That looks like a brick fell out or in, and critter(s) have been using it for access to the building. Can you get a picture from under the deck?

Comment: Thanks for fast response. Just uploaded new photos.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like some bricks fell out (or in?). A mason or a DIY mason could put the bricks back in, perhaps.

A possibility: Try taking out the schmutz X'd out here:

[image: bricks to remove]

Then see about either adding bricks from below (can a mason do bricks upside down?) or fill the hole with some pressure-treated wood or plywood.